# D7 - db_select: order by most recent, commented status

Tags: 7, database

I'm writing my custom module.
I use the modules [Statuses](http://drupal.org/project/statuses) and 'fbss_comments' (part of the Statuses module). Comments are used to comment on statuses.

Using the following code I get a list of results:

```
 $query = db_select("statuses", "thread")->distinct();
        $query->join("fbss_comments", "comment", "comment.sid = thread.sid");
        $query->fields("thread", array("sid", "sender", "created", "message"));
        $query->fields("comment", array("created"));
        $query->orderBy("comment.created", "DESC");
        $result = $query->execute();
```

Now the list of results will be sorted by the most recent posted status. I want to achieve the following: **sort the result list by statuses with the most recent comments**

Some clarification: normally status(100) will be shown above status(30). When I comment on status(30), status(30) should be shown above status(100). On top of this, when I create a new status(101), this status should be shown on top of the result list.

I hope my goal is clear to you, sadly, I have no idea how to achieve this.

Any advice or help is much appreciated

**edit:** I've managed to order the results by the most recent commented statuses, however, if a status has 9 comments, the status is shown 9 times. Any advice why/how this happens?

**edit 2:** I probably should use ->distinct(), I've added it after the db select statement, but  this doesn't work (probably because I select two tables)

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without seeing the new code, you created. If you create SQL fiddle with test data and your request, it will be very helpful.

Comment: "if a status has 9 comments, the status is shown 9 times. Any advice why/how this happens?" It happens, because you created a query, fetching the data from 2 related tables. And it returns all the corresponding rows from both tables.

Comment: Why are you fetching `sid` field twice: once from the 1-st table, then from the 2-nd table?

Comment: good question, now I only select 'created' from the fbss_comments table. Doesn't make any visual difference though. If distinct the right approach to make sure a status is only shown once? thanks for your help so far btw.

Answer (score 3):

You have a classical case, that requires using '`HAVING`' `SQL` operator. Suppose, we have 2 related tables:

```
| table1 |
|--------|
|   id   |
|--------|
|    1   |
|    2   |
|--------|
```

table2.f_id is the FK for table1.id

```
|         table2        |
|--------+------+-------|
|     id | f_id | order |
|--------+------+-------|
|      1 |    1 |     1 |
|      2 |    1 |     2 |
|      3 |    2 |     3 |
|      4 |    2 |     4 |
|--------+------+-------|
```

And you want to get all the records from table1 with MAX of the related table2.order. And sort them by table2.order. You must use this SQL to get the data:

```
SELECT
  table1.id AS id1,
  table2.id AS id2,
  table2.order
FROM
    table1
INNER JOIN
    table2
ON
    table1.id=table2.f_id
GROUP BY
    table1.id
HAVING
    MAX(table2.order)
ORDER BY
    table2.order DESC
```

And you will get:

```
| id | id1 | order |
|----+-----+-------|
|  2 |   3 |     3 |
|  1 |   1 |     1 |
|----+-----+-------|
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6325/2)

Converting this SQL to Drupal, we'll get this:

```
$query = db_select("table1");
$query->innerJoin("table2", NULL, "table1.id=table2.f_id");
$query->addField("table1", "id", "id1");
$query->addField("table2", "id", "id2");
$query->addField("table2", "order", "order_field");

$query->groupBy("table1.id");
$query->having("MAX(table2.order)");
$query->orderBy("table2.order", "DESC");
$result = $query->execute();
while($row = $result->fetchAssoc())
{
      var_dump($row);
}
```

So, for your case, this query must work:

```
$query = db_select("statuses", "thread");
$query->innerJoin("fbss_comments", "comment", "comment.sid = thread.sid");
$query->fields("thread", array("sid", "sender", "created", "message"));
$query->fields("comment", array("created"));

$query->groupBy("thread.sid");
$query->having("MAX(comment.created)");
$query->orderBy("comment.created", "DESC");
$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your extensive answer, I'll test it within a few hours and report back.

Comment: hmm sorry but it's not correct, now I only get statuses with comments (of course, join..). I need to show all statuses, and sort by most recent comments on statuses + most recent status. So either the latest status is on top or the status with the latest comment. this is really hard.. :( shouldn't we use outer join / union?

Comment: @MaartenHartman It's hard to answer without seeing, what is the data and what result does the request produce. Plz, create a fiddle.

Comment: @MaartenHartman IF you still can't fix it, I can come to char for a while.

Comment: thank you so much for your help mate. I've decided to solve this in a much easier way: I will just update the timestamp of the status when a comment has been posted to it. In this way I will achieve the same result in a very simple way :) thanks again.

Comment: what shall I do with this question? delete or just leave it open?

Comment: @MaartenHartman Leave it open. I think my answer is good and could be useful for others.